# Clone Windows to External Drive and Make Grub Aware of It

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, fedora, grub

My current setup contains the following operations systems

- Windows 10 Home Edition
- Fedora 34

I rarely use Windows 10, pretty much only in case I want to update some settings in MSI Dragon, e.g. capping battery charging to 60% to improve battery life, or (rarely) play some games not available on Linux.

With this limited use, I am annoyed with having Windows using a lot of space on my main disk and I would like to move it to an external drive. Windows doesn't allow me to install a fresh copy on an external disk for some reason. So, I was thinking of doing the following:

- Copy the entire NTFS partition containing Windows and all its data to an external NTFS partition.
- Wipe out my entire laptop disk and install a fresh copy of Fedora using the entire disk.
- After having the fresh copy of Fedora, update Grub to have an entry for the Windows copy in the external drive.

Would this work? If not, any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Notes:

- I am not worried about the current Windows data, so if there is a way to install Windows on an external drive after installing a fresh Fedora copy, I don't mind it.
- I don't want to use any proprietary software.

Thanks!

Comment: You won’t be able to do this without some kind of third-party software.  If your willing to just simply reinstall Windows, Rufus can install it, but Windows 2 Go installations are absolutely not going to be want you want fair warning (and they are the only way to boot Windows on an external drive)

Comment: An external USB will be too slow for gaming.

Comment: @Ramhound, Rufus only creates bootable images, no?

Comment: @harrymc, honestly, I don't mind, nowadays I am not even playing games on Windows. So, I really just want to have Windows in case I want to make some MSI Dragon changes, or any other little thing that requires Windows.

Comment: I used Macrium Reflect to free-gratis move Win10 from a 1TB HDD to a smaller ~280GB SSD. The duplication was using the SSD connected over USB3. I didn't test it, but I see no reason it wouldn't boot from the SSD connected to USB?

Comment: Another idea: Why not convert the Windows partition to a virtual machine?

Comment: @pbhj, I haven't heard of this software before;  I will check it. Whether it works or not I guess depends on what was copied to the external drive, i.e. just the operating system or the boot-related stuff.

Comment: @harrymc, I thought about creating a Virtual Machine, but will it be the same as a real OS? I suppose MSI Dragon has some mechanism to access the BIOS and make changes to things like the maximum charging level, and I am not sure whether it would work when it is running on a virthual machine. Also, what about the license? My license it is attached to the laptop, so will a Windows running on a virtual machine pick the hardware info correctly?

Comment: Rufus supports creating a Windows 2 Go install; You won’t be able to duplicate your current install on a removable drive and boot to it

Comment: Hmm.. I never noticed that. Ok, thanks, I will give it a try and see.

Comment: Windows usually stays activated after virtualization and the VM is in working condition.

Comment: I ended up following Ramhound's suggestion of creating a Windows to Go on an external hard drive and it worked for me, though incredibly slow, but that's because I am using a very old hard disk. This is sufficient for me for now, I only need it every now and then, but I guess if it starts to bother me, I will just buy a faster disk.

Comment: FWIW @Promather I only used it once, I copied the EFI and primary boot (c:) partitions and it all just worked. The drive being duplicated was an OEM installation on a Lenovo laptop using EFI with secureboot enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I followed one of the suggestions in the comment and created a Windows to Go image using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).